# Remote Desktop Session disconnects sporadically

Tags: windows-server-2012, remote-desktop, rdp, remote-desktop-services

Problem: RDP session disconnect and reconnect. Effects most user RDP sessions not all. Some remote users on our server sporadically gets disconnected. Their remote session freezes and they get a small window saying:

> The session has been lost. Attempting to reconnect your session. Connection attempt 1 of 20.

Then they get reconnected mostly on the first try. To users that are facing this problem, this happens often.

Environment: Windows Server 2012 on Workgroup setting (not active directory). Dell PowerEdge T420 machine with 32GB Ram. CPU consumption mostly in 30%-40% range. RAM in ~60% range.

Answer (score 2):

This is indicative of a poor network connection. If only some users have this problem a good next step is to identify how those users connect (wired, mobile broadband, wifi, etc.) and where they are working (at home, in an office, in public).

If it is happening to all of your users check your server adapter settings and verify the server is not seeing packet loss.

Chances are some of your users are connecting to the server using an unreliable wireless signal.